SQL connecting url string not taking into account the connection properties
I want to access a SQL Server database by using connetorx and it seems that the connection properties are not taken into account. The multisubnetfailover=yes is ignored and the connection is sometimes failing. Are the connection properties correctly passed after the question mark character?
conn = f"mssql://{username}:{quote_plus(password)}@{server}:{port}/{database}?driver=SQL+Server&MultiSubnetFailover=yes"


Consider not using driver=SQL+Server, which is probably selecting the deprecated SQL Server Native Client library (that hasn't received feature updates since SQL Server 2012 days and is no longer shipped as of SQL Server 2022). Do you have modern and supported libraries installed, such as ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server or ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server?

driver=SQL+Server is no longer maintained.
Instead use ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server or ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server.
If using connectorx:
conn = (
    f"mssql://{username}:{quote_plus(password)}@{server}:{port}/{database}"
    "?driver=ODBC+Driver+18+for+SQL+Server&MultiSubnetFailover=Yes"
)

